# After I have implemented Getx state management "The getter 'visible' was called on null."

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I just started learning `dart/flutter` and really love the flutter framework, but I running into a problem when I started play with some state management, and I have chosen `Getx`. After I have integrate the `state management` into my project... I start to have this problem

```sh
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The getter 'visible' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: visible
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
```

and already become quite hard for me to debug. If anyone here can give some light on how can I fix this error... will be fantastic.

My model

```sh
class TransactionModel {
  List<Data> data;

  TransactionModel({
    this.data,
  });

  factory TransactionModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Data> transactions = new List<Data>();
    transactions = parsedJson.map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return TransactionModel(
      data: transactions ?? transactions,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String id;
  String title;
  double amount;
  String created;
  String fileUrl;

  Data({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.amount,
    this.created,
    this.fileUrl,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'].toString() ?? json['id'].toString();
    title = json['title'] ?? json['title'];
    amount = json['amount'] ?? json['amount'];
    created = json['created'] ?? json['created'];
    fileUrl = json['fileUrl'] ?? json['fileUrl'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    data['id'] = this.id ?? this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title ?? this.title;
    data['amount'] = this.amount ?? this.amount;
    data['created'] = this.created ?? this.created;
    data['fileUrl'] = this.fileUrl ?? this.fileUrl;

    return data;
  }
}
```

My controller

```sh
class TransactionController extends GetxController {
  var trasanctionListData = List<Data>().obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    _getTransactionList();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void _getTransactionList() async {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration.zero,
      () => Get.dialog(
        Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
        barrierDismissible: false,
      ),
    );

    Request request = Request(url: 'transactions', body: null);
    request.get().then((value) {
      TransactionModel transactionModel = TransactionModel.fromJson(
        json.decode(value.body),
      );
      trasanctionListData.value = transactionModel.data;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      Get.rawSnackbar(
        title: 'Error',
        message: '${onError.message}',
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: AppColors.greyishBrown,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

My view

```sh
class TransactionView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TransactionController _controller =
        Get.put<TransactionController>(TransactionController());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.cloudyWhite,
      appBar: MiAppBar(title: 'Overview'),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Carousel(),
            Obx(
              () => ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _controller.trasanctionListData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => TransactionItem(
                  key: ValueKey(_controller.trasanctionListData[index].id),
                  title: _controller.trasanctionListData[index].title,
                  amount: _controller.trasanctionListData[index].amount,
                  createdAt: _controller.trasanctionListData[index].created,
                  deleteOnClick: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and paying attention to the error message, I found that the problem for my case was; that the listView was looking for the height of the parent, and in my case the parent was the Obx widget and then the column and  those widgets haven't  a defined height, and I fixed  my problem by wrapping the Obx widget with a Container widget, and give a height to the Container widget.  I don't know if is the right solution, but for me work.